# how can I view the data get from database to my gridview using php?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, vuejs2

I've been stuck with the same problem for 2 days. now I'm working how to display a value from database which is many to many relation.

the case now I need to search bill no from bill table in database which i have done it but i'm stuck with displaying the value which the value of bill no from bill table, collection name from collection table, organization name from organization table relate account id in account table relate to bill table in account id, and need to display customer name full name(first+last).

this my billsController

```
public function actionLoadRequest($order_number)
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return $this->asJson([
                "status" => false,
                "message" => "Unknown request method.",
                "data" => []
            ]);
        }

        $data = Bill::find()->where(['bill_no'=>$order_number])->one();


        return $this->asJson([
            "status" => true,
            "message" => "",
            "data" => $data
        ]);
    }
```

this is my view

```
<template v-if="isLoading">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="7" class="center aligned">Processing...</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </template>
                                            <template v-else>
                                                <template v-if="data.length > 0">
                                                    <tr v-for="$bill in data">
                                                        <td>{{bill.bill_no}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{bill.collection}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{bill.organization}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{account.first_name + " " + account.last_name}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{bill.currency + " " +
                                                            bill.Amount}}
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </template>
                                                <template v-if="data.length === 0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="7" class="center aligned">No request data.</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </template>
                                            </template>
```

this is my javascript

```
methods: {
                loadRequest: function () {
                    console.log(this.bill_no);
                    if (this.bill_no === "") {
                        alert("Nothing to search. Please enter bill number.");
                        return;
                    }

                    let self = this;

                    self.isLoading = true;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?= Url::to(["/admin/bills/load-request"]) ?>",
                        method: 'GET',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {order_number: this.bill_no}
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {

                            self.data = data.data;

                        } else {
                            alert(data.message);
                            self.data = [];
                        }
                        console.log(data);
                        self.isLoading = false;
                    }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                        if (jqXHR.responseJSON) {
                            alert("Nothing to search. Please enter bill number.");
                        } else {
                            alert("Nothing to search. Please enter bill number.");
                        }

                        self.isLoading = false;
                    });


                },

            },
```

Edit-----------------------------

I have solve my problem for displaying data from database by change the code in my controller

```
$data = Bill::find()
            ->where(['bill_no'=>$bill_number])
            ->asArray()
            ->all();
```

but I have a problem with a relationship as I still new with vue js.

[my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbxWI.png)

Comment: `v-for="$bill in data"` dont think you want the `$`

Comment: Can you show your data section

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you were right. the code I give is before I edit it yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that using of Pjax. In Pjax you have history of the AJAX events without refreshing the page.

And too, you can have clean code in your Action, View and JS file.

You can see help full in link : [Yii2 Pjax Tutorial](http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-pjax-tutorial/)

Comment: supposedly using Pjax does help me. but this is a continuation from my partner coding model. this is my first time using yue js so I kinda lost a little here.

Answer (score 0):

i guess did you need something like this?:

```
$data = Bill::find()->where(['bill_no'=>$order_number])->one();
$account_name = $data->collection->organization->account->name;
```

obviously the collection, organization and account are relationship names made in your Bills Model.

Hope it helped a little.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

in your Bill model class, create a method names getCollection() like following

```
// this function declare a relation named `collection`, notice the C in getCollection is upper case
public function getCollection()
{
    // the `id` is a column in table collection, `collection_id` is a column in table bill, `Collection` is the model class correspond with table collection
    return $this->hasOne(Collection::class, ['id' => 'collection_id']);

    // if you define foreign key in collection table to refer `id` in bill table, use following
    return $this->hasOne(Collection::class, ['bill_id' => 'id']);
}
```

then in your controller, add `with` function call with argument `collection`

```
$data = Bill::find()
            ->where(['bill_no'=>$bill_number])
            // there `collection` is the relation you just create, make sure its name is correct, notice the letter case 
            ->with('collection')
            ->asArray()
            ->all();
```

after that, you will find out $data['collection'] is that collection you expected.
Similarly, add other relations in your Bill model class and call `with` function with your relation as argument.

refer this https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#declaring-relations

hope to help you

Comment: I already your method. apparently, I can't get the data to display correctly instead I get the error shows "500 internal error".

Comment: Is there any error message dumped ? BTW, I add some comment and a refer link, hope to help you